# NWJS (Node Webkit) app is not responding on Linux systems when I use it with Web Workers

Tags: node.js, web-worker, node-webkit, nw.js, nwjs

NWJS Version: v.0.32.1 (Tested on different 0.31 versions also and 0.32.beta)
Operating System: Linux only. Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64 and Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki x64

#### Expected behaviour

The program must respond.

#### Actual behaviour

The program not responding and if I break it (`Ctrl + C`) i seen in console that messages: 

`[14399:14410:0802/142733.750943:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(104)] Error sending sync broker message: Broken pipe (32)
[14399:14410:0802/142733.761023:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(104)] Error sending sync broker message: Broken pipe (32)
[14399:14409:0802/142733.761203:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(104)] Error sending sync broker message: Broken pipe (32)
[14399:14409:0802/142733.761402:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(104)] Error sending sync broker message: Broken pipe (32)
[14399:14409:0802/142733.761801:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(104)] Error sending sync broker message: Broken pipe (32)
[14399:14410:0802/142733.761896:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(104)] Error sending sync broker message: Broken pipe (32)`

But if I'am using `nwjs-builder-phoenix` and running SDK - working correctly.

### How to reproduce

#### Prepare

1. Download and extract fake data to parsing: https://github.com/trofivan/myq-jobs-archive-parser/releases/download/v0.1.0/fake-data-big.zip
2. `git clone https://github.com/trofivan/myq-jobs-archive-parser.git`
3. `cd myq-jobs-archive-parser`
4. `npm i`

#### Working correctly (only with nwjs-builder-phoenix SDK)

1. `npm start`
2. In the opened window click `Select folder to parse`
3. Select folder with fake data
4. Wait some time while data will have parsed.
5. Use filters
6. Close the program

#### Working not correctly

1. `npm run build.dist`
2. `cd dist/myq-jobs-archive-parser-0.1.3-linux-x64/`
3. `./myq-jobs-archive-parser`
4. Select folder to parse and waiting some time.
5. **The program does not respond**.
6. Close program (`Ctrl + C or [x] on the window`) and see console output:
   `Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.`
   `[16012:16023:0802/145405.677499:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(104)] Error sending sync broker message: Broken pipe (32)`
   `[16012:16023:0802/145405.678176:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(104)] Error sending sync broker message: Broken pipe (32)`
   `[16012:16012:0802/145405.679403:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(104)] Error sending sync broker message: Broken pipe (32)`
   `[16012:16012:0802/145405.679587:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(100)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: AllocateAndMapSharedMemory failed`
7. `killall exe` - to stop the process

### PS:

- If download nwjs from the official website, working not correctly with SDK version also.
- On Linux system program not responded when comes to the game Web Worker: https://github.com/trofivan/myq-jobs-archive-parser/blob/master/src/middlewares/fetchJobs.js
- When program not responding I'm can not open Chrome dev tools and get more info.